# How do I have a category assigned to the hurricane based on it's wind speed In Python

Tags: python

Hello I am trying to code a program were the computer will randomly generate a wind speed, storm surge for a hurricane. So far It will randomly generate those two things. But now I can't figure out how to callback the variable wind speed from the function wind into the function category to use the randomly generated wind speed to define what category it is. But when ever I run the program it will print the wind speed and storm surge but when it prints the category it does not print it correlated to the wind speed. Here is my code.

```
import os
import sys
import random
import math 
import time

def wind():
    windspeed = randrange(74, 157)
    print "The Hurricanes wind speed is"
    time.sleep(2)
    print windspeed

def stormsurge():
    surgeamount = randrange(3, 19)
    print "The Hurricanes storm storm surge is"
    time.sleep(2)
    print surgeamount

def category():
    categorys = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5]
    for windspeed in range(74, 95):
        print categorys[0]
   else:
       for windspeed in range(96, 110):
           print categorys[1]

wind()
stormsurge()
category()
```

And when I run it I get.
    [After running it](https://i.stack.imgur.com/oRmT0.png)

Comment: I see functions and `for` loops, but no `if` statements. Do you know about `if` statements? Because that'll be the easiest way for you.

Comment: Yes, but when I do it says windspeed is not defined because windspeed is not a variable that is in category. And i am trying to recall the outcome of the randomly generated windspeed to tell it what category it should be.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

You can use something like this:

```
import os
import sys
import random
import math 

def wind():
   windspeed = random.randrange(74, 157)
   print "The Hurricanes wind speed is", windspeed
   return windspeed

def stormsurge():
   surgeamount = random.randrange(3, 19)
   print "The Hurricanes storm storm surge is", surgeamount
   return surgeamount

def category(windspeed, surgeamount):
   categorys = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5]
   for _windspeed in range(74, 95):
         if _windspeed == windspeed:
            print "Storm category is", categorys[0]
            break
   else:
      for _windspeed in range(96, 157):
         if _windspeed == windspeed:
            print "Storm category is", categorys[1]

windspeed = wind()
surgeamount = stormsurge()
category(windspeed, surgeamount)
```

Or even simpler:

```
import os
import sys
import random
import math 

def wind():
   windspeed = random.randrange(74, 157)
   print "The Hurricanes wind speed is", windspeed
   return windspeed

def stormsurge():
   surgeamount = random.randrange(3, 19)
   print "The Hurricanes storm storm surge is", surgeamount
   return surgeamount

def category(windspeed, surgeamount):
   categorys = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5]
   if windspeed in range(74, 95):
      print "Storm category is", categorys[0]
   else:
      print "Storm category is", categorys[1]

windspeed = wind()
surgeamount = stormsurge()
category(windspeed, surgeamount)
```

Do not forget use return value from functions ')

Comment: Your `category` function makes no sense. Did you try running it?

Comment: @Jon Kiparsky: Relax, it is not my code even. I have just corrected it to be workable =)

Comment: I'm perfectly relaxed, but it still doesn't make any sense.

Comment: Yes i Posted a picture of what it does https://i.stack.imgur.com/oRmT0.png

Comment: @Rustywithpythonagain: Try last one and you'll see it does not produce something simular from your picture after correction )

Comment: @DenisKotov Some fundamental problems here: the parameter `surgeamount` is not used, this function will only ever return category of 1 or 2 (what happens if the windspeed is 119?), the category function prints output rather than returning a value (what if you want to use the category for something?), and "categorys" is misspelled. Please review some basics before you confuse newbies.

Comment: I just added on it to make it go higher.

Answer (score 0):

```
def wind():
    windspeed = randrange(74, 157)
    print "The Hurricanes wind speed is"
    time.sleep(2)
    print windspeed
```

This function effectively prints a random number in the range (74, 157). If you want to be able to work with that number, you have to return a value:

```
def wind():
    return randrange(74, 157)
```

Then the calling function can do what it needs to do with that result - presumably, it'll start by saving it to some variable, and then it might print the value or calculate a category or something like that.

If you want to calculate a category based on some number, the most obvious way to do it would be something like the following:

```
def category(windspeed):
  # based on http://www.nhc.noaa.gov/aboutsshws.php
  if windspeed < 74:
    return 0 
  elif 75 <= windspeed < 96:
    return 1 
  if 96 <= windspeed < 111:
    return 2
  elif 111 <= windspeed < 120:
    return 3
  elif 130 <= windspeed < 157:
    return 4
  else: 
    return 5
```

your code would look something like the following:

```
windspeed = wind()
hurricane_category = category(windspeed)
print "The windspeed is %d and the category is %d" % (
  windspeed, hurricane_category)
```

Comment: `return = randrange`?

Comment: See the edited post. You might want to take a look at something like Zed Shaw's "Learn Python the Hard Way", since it sounds like you need a good refresher on the basics.